# How can I put plus/minus in if?

Tags: mysql, sql

This has always made me wondered,

Lets say I have this situation :

```
select (...long sub query..) - (...long sub query..)
```

And I want to put the `-` in condition, meaning sometimes it will be `-` and sometimes `+`, Is there an easy way to do this?
The way I know is :

```
select if(condition,(...long sub query..) - (...long sub query..),
   (...long sub query..) + (...long sub query..))
```

Which makes the query harder to read and maintain, or puting it into a stored procedure, which i'd rather not.

Can i put the arithmetic operation in some kind of var and concat it somehow?

What i'm trying to achive is something like :

```
select (...long sub query..) if(condition,-,+) (...long sub query..)
```

Comment: can you put together a concrete example on SQL Fiddle?  it is difficult to relate from this abstract example

Comment: @amphibient: He doesn't want to re-use the subqueries in the `IF`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't.

However, you can use multiplication instead:

```
(...) + IF(..., -1, +1) * (...)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `query1 + query2 * if()`?

Comment: @eric.itzhak: Multiplication is commutative

Comment: If someone asks, i never said the above :)

Comment: @eric.itzhak: Plus multiplication comes first.  Order of operations :)

Answer (score 0):

You can save each subquery in a variable, then use the variables in the `IF`.

```
SELECT @a:=(...long sub query..), @b:=(...long sub query..),
  IF(condition, @a-@b, @a+@b) AS result
```

Docs for MySQL variables: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html

Answer (score -1):

didn't much understand your question but you can store any character in string or char  variable and use it to concatenate in your statement